# Неправильно работает предпросмотр при указании языка в цитате

Tags: дефект, markdown

Если написать вот так

```
    Dim X As Integer = 0 ' Default

<!-- language: lang-vb -->

    Dim X As Integer = 0 ' VB
```

то получится:

```
Dim X As Integer = 0 ' Default
```

```vb
Dim X As Integer = 0 ' VB
```

А вопрос в том, как запихнуть это в цитату. С первым вариантом всё понятно:

```
>     Dim X As Integer = 0 ' Default
```

> ```
> Dim X As Integer = 0 ' Default
> ```

А вот со вторым есть сложности:

```
> <!-- language: lang-vb -->
>
>     Dim X As Integer = 0 ' VB
```

И работает неправильно, и наверху отступ явно лишний:

> ```vb
> Dim X As Integer = 0 ' VB
> ```

Впрочем, оказывается, косяк только в предпросмотре при написании сообщения:

[image: скриншот до отправки]

А вот после отправки уже всё хорошо:

[image: скриншот после отправки]